# How to add dart language to CodeRunner App in MacOS?

Tags: macos, dart, coderunner

I want to add new language in coderunner app [MacOS]. which just works like [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true).
I installed flutter sdk.
but I got this error message when I tried to compile the code after selecting the dart language which I added by Preferences/Languages/Add new language (+ symbol) :

```
/bin/sh: dart: command not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open CodeRunner app.
2. Go to `CodeRunner/Preferences/Languages`.
3. Click on the `+` button at the end of the languages to add another language.
   [image: CodeRunner Preferences]
4. Do the following steps to setup Dart as language mode in coderunner app :

- Rename language name from *Untitled* to `Dart`.
- Set Run Command as `dart $filename`.
- Set File Extension as `.dart`.
- Set Syntax mode as `Dart`.

[image: Dart language setup in coderunner]
5. Install Dart using *HomeBrew* in **Terminal** :

```
- brew tap dart-lang/dart
- brew install dart
```

If you get any error, try this before executing above commands :

```
export ALL_PROXY=$http_proxy:port
```

If you get any error like : `Error: Your Command Line Tools are too outdated.`

then try this :
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:

```
softwareupdate --all --install --force
```

If that doesn't show you any updates, run:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install
```

6. Now, let’s run sample dart code by selecting Dart as language and writing *Hello World* dart code :
   [image: sample dart code run]

## Dart setup successfully :)